# Internet connection problem after new wireless network created Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, wifi, ubuntu-9.10

I want to share internet connection from my ubuntu box with my smartphone. The problem is when I try create new wireless network via GUI, I have problems with my internet connection. I guess that my machine is still connected to the internet physically, but I cannot access any website via web browser. Also, I can connect to wireless network via my smartphone, but again, I cannot browse the internet.
I use Ubuntu 9.10 Desktop edition. My wi-fi adapter is TP-LINK TL-WN821N.
If you need some more info - please feel free to ask. I'm not professional system administration and I don't even know what information should I provide.

EDIT: IP routing is allowed on my machine.

Here are route command outputs:
Before I create wireless network:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
stream-ts1.net. *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.8.65.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
```

After I create wireless network:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
stream-ts1.net. *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.42.43.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan2
10.8.65.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
default         10.8.65.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/14354/

But... It may require two separate network adapters (e.g. 2 wireless, wireless & wired, etc.) depending on the capabilities of your wireless hardware versus its available device driver capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you only need to define a new default route (host 0.0.0.0 and gateway on your internet adapter network) for your machine. What is the output of `route` command? (would be safer to change or mask your public IPs in the output)

You may also need to allow IP routing on your machine as I don't know if your GUI installer did that for you (and the default is disabled) but you can check with:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

If it says `0`, it is not enabled and you can do `/bin/echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to enable it (as root)

Comment: IP routing is allowed.

Comment: Seeing the routes you posted, try to do `sudo route del default` and `sudo route add default dev ppp0` to rebuild your original default rule and see if it works. If yes, you'll have to persist this change in your create wireless script (or better, disable the change the script is doing to your default route)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the gateway in your configuration.  It is being moved from your ppp connection to eth0.  Don't set the gateway for either the wireless or ethernet adapter.